# Web Servers and REST Methods

Tags: http, rest, browser, webserver

Most web browsers support only HTTP methods like `GET` and `POST` and do not support `PUT` and `DELETE`.

If so, does web servers like IIS and Apache support it? Why should them support if the web browsers don't supports them? Those methods can be used for something else?

Comment: browsers don't emit PUT/DELETE themselves, but javascript can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web servers support these verbs because they are part of the HTTP specification and because browsers are not the only clients of web servers especially in the Web 2.0 era. There are more and more RESTful APIs today.